# PHP/MySQL - Include an error-page if the row don't exist in the database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to display an error-page if row ID is not present in the database. Here's my code:

db.php:

```
 public function getRow()
 {
     $arr = array();
     $get_id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '';
     $val_id = intval($get_id);
     $rowId = $val_id > 0 ? $val_id : '';
     $statement = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT id, username, date, comment from table where id = $rowId");
     //echo $this->conn->error;
     $statement->bind_result($id, $username, $date, $comment);
     $statement->execute();
     while ($statement->fetch()) {
         $arr[] = [ "id" => $id, "username" => $username, "date" => $date, "comment" => $comment];
     }
     $statement->close();

     return $arr;
 }
```

The main content:

```
<?php
    require_once("./config/db.php");
    $arr = $conn->getRow();
    $get_id = isset($_GET['id']) ?  $_GET['id'] : '';
    $val_id = intval($get_id);
    $rowId = $val_id > 0 ? $val_id : '';

    for($i=0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
        if ($rowId === $arr[$i]['id'] && $arr[$i]['username'] === $_SESSION['username']) {
            $id = $rowId;
            $date = $arr[$i]['date'];
            $comment = $arr[$i]['comment'];

            echo $id;
            echo $date;
            echo $comment;
        } else if ($arr[$i]['id'] = NULL || $arr[$i]['username'] !== $_SESSION['username']) {
            include './content/404.php';
        }
    }
?>
```

I get it to display the error-page when the user-name is wrong, but when I call a row ID that doesn't exist, it ony returns a blank page.

I'm grateful if anyone can help me spot the error here.
Thanks!

Comment: does your 404.php contains something? makes sure that this file doesn't contain blank page.

Comment: `$arr[$i]['id'] = NULL` assigns NULL to `$arr[$i]['id']`. Perhaps you meant `==`?

Comment: 404.php has content. The content of 404.php is displayed when the username is wrong.

Comment: Thank you @David, but that did unfortunately not solve the main issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to check for id inside looping. You have filtered it inside `getRow()` function. If this function returns a non-empty value, the value surely contains a matched id.

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
    $id = $rowId;
    $date = $arr[$i]['date'];
    $comment = $arr[$i]['comment'];

    echo $id;
    echo $date;
    echo $comment;
}

if (count($arr) == 0) { // execute if $arr is empty
    include './content/404.php';
}
```